# Alignment issue in the CAPTCHA window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, captcha

There is an alignment issue in the CAPTCHA window.

- Some time the I'm not a robot checkbox went out of the modal window.

[image]

- Some time the modal window occupying the full width of the page, it expected to aligned center.

[image]

The issue found on Mozilla Firefox 67.0 (64-bit) in Windows 10, with 100% Zoom.

Comment: This was corrected in a past Stacks release, marking it as completed.